# Evaluate singularity in numerical iterative physical optics integral

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, singularities

My goal is to implement a code to numerically compute the radar cross section (RCS) of an open-ended PEC cavity by the approach of "iterative physical optics" [1]. The idea is to iteratively compute the current distribution on the PEC surface (to account for multiple scattering), from which the far field can finally be derived. In the approach, the cavity surface $S_c$ is discretized by flat (triangular or rectangular) facets (with a side length of 0.5 to 0.33 times the wavelength), and a constant current density $J(\vec{r}_c)$ is assumed per facet. The location of a cavity facet is given by $\vec{r}_c$.

Now the central part of the IPO algorithm is the repeated evaluation of an integral of the form

$$ 
\vec{J}_N(\vec{r}_c) = \ldots + 2\hat{n} \times -\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{S_c} \vec{J}_{N-1}(\vec{r}_c') \times \nabla G_0(\vec{r}_c - \vec{r}_c') dS_c'
$$

where

$$
\nabla G_0(\vec{R}) = \hat{R} \left(jk + \frac{1}{R} \right) \frac{e^{-jkR}}{4\pi R}
$$
is the gradient of the free space Green's function with $R = |\vec{R}|$ and $\hat{R} = \vec{R}/R$.

My question is: **How can the principal value integral be implemented? How can the singularity in the integral (for $R = 0$) be handled?** Note that for the IPO approach, the integral is replaced by a sum over the cavity facets (assuming a constant current density per facet).

The problem of computing the diagonal elements of the resulting matrix must come up repeatedly in similar algorithms. How is this typically handled?

I have found approaches which replace the surface integral by a line integral along the triangle edges [2]. This would require to determine the fields at the mesh vertices also (and not only at the facet centroids), which apparently wasn't done by the original authors. What am I missing? Apparently the self-patch integral can also be solved analytically, but I would expect a much less efficient code. I am confused...

Thanks for any pointers!

---

[1] Obelleiro-Basteiro, F., Rodriguez, J. L., & Burkholder, R. J. (1995). An Iterative Physical Optics Approach for Analyzing the Electromagnetic Scattering by Large Open-Ended Cavities. IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation, 43(4), 356–361.

[2] Graglia, R. D. (1993). On the numerical integration of the linear shape functions times the 3-D Green’s function or its gradient on a plane triangle. IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation, 41(10), 1448–1455.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: It turns out that the self-term element can just be skipped when the sum (approximation of the integral) is computed. This is because the $\hat{n} \times$ removes the component anyhow. A practial implementation confirms that the results are useful.